# Scheduling Concurrent Jobs in Java

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, scheduler

I have implemented Schedulers in java in my code using 2 different ways. However, both seem to work in sequential rather than parallel thread. mine is a spring 4 application on java 8.

first way

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/59 * * * * *")
public void test2 (){
```

second way

```
 @Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    try{

        taskRegistrar.addTriggerTask(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override public void run() {
                        try {

                            System.out.println("some configure task running every 10 seconds --" + new Date());
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                },
                new Trigger() {
                    @Override public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
                        Calendar nextExecutionTime =  Calendar.getInstance();

                        Date lastActualExecutionTime = triggerContext.lastActualExecutionTime();
                        nextExecutionTime.setTime(lastActualExecutionTime != null ? lastActualExecutionTime : new Date());

                        nextExecutionTime.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1000); 
                        return nextExecutionTime.getTime();
                    }
                }
        );
```

both are not working in concurrent mode. this is huge inconsistency in the jobs. like for example i want a job to run every 100 seconds, is never starts at every 100 seconds. it could be a delay of more than 3-4 mins as well depending upon completion of previous job.
can somebody please point to a better solution. thanks

i tried the following as was suggested below.

```
ConcurrentTaskScheduler scheduler =  new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(new Date() +"start of test2 crons job running every 59 seconds test2 test2 test2");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(new Date() +"end of test2 crons job running every 59 seconds end end end ");
        }
    }, new CronTrigger("0/30 * * * * *"));
```

i created 5 such jobs and ran them but they are still running sequential. i am not able to find my mistake here or if somebody has any code snippet or any link where i can find any sample code would be very helpful.

Comment: `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` is your best friend

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, it depends on the particular `TaskExecutor` that you use. There are several of which you could choose for your case. Please refer to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor-types for the different executors that Spring provides.

Comment: i tried to create the following code. this is also not concurrent. it is still sequential. can you help me with a mistake or a probable code snippet if you have

Comment: I didn't mean for you to create the executor yourself. In your spring configuration, you could specify the task executor to be used. That way, your @Schedule methods will be invoked using the specified executor. Check the link I provided, it includes examples of the configuration as well.